# default font in Balsamiq, how to change? [off-topic]

Tags: font, balsamiq

Can we change the default font of the components in Balsamiq?

size 13(default) --> size 24 (what I want)

thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking how to use a specific program.

Comment: Unrelatedly, but people coming here might be looking to *download* the default font that balsamiq uses: *balsamiq sans*, which is [available from balsamiq](https://balsamiq.com/products/mockups/font/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please follow the steps as shown in below image. you can change the font and default font size.

[image]